# how to access iframe textbox id in current page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iframe

Friends I have a Parent Page(default.aspx) that includes an iframe page(iframe.aspx) containing textbox in the  field. The parent page contains the "Save" button. Now i want to get the values of iframe page while submitting the parent page. How can i access the iframe pages fields in parent page submit?

iframe.aspx page,,,,
In Iframe page i have two textbox,,

```
<asp:textbox id="txtfromdate" runat="server"></asp:textbox> 
<asp:textbox id="txttodate" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
```

default.aspx page

```
<iframe id="iframebody" runat="server" src="iframe.aspx" style="width:900px; height:600px"></iframe>

<asp:button id="submit" text="save" runat="server" />
```

frdz how to access iframe page id(txtfromdate, txtTodate) in parrent page(default.aspx) when i click on button??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this javascript on the button click.

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="txtHidData" runat="server" />
```

**Javascript**

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframebody');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var usernameTextBox = innerDoc.getElementById('txtfromdate');
document.getElementById ( "txtHidData" ).value = usernameTextBox.value;
```

**C#**

```
string valueInCodeBehind = txtHidData.Value;
```

Comment: @pravn--> thanks frd, i'll try now,, do yu know how to access id in code behind?

Comment: you can put a hidden field in the page. Then using above javascript assign the value of fromdate to that hidden value. Then in the code behind, you can access the hidden field value.

Comment: @pravn-->thanks frd, is their possible, can yu give me example for that??

Answer (score 0):

You can not access iframe's content with server side code.

For accessing content of iframe, you should use javascript.

In jquery, you can access it :

```
var iFrameContent = $('#iframebody').content();
var fromDate = iFrameContent.find('#txtfromdate').val();
var toDate= iFrameContent.find('#txttodate').val();
```

store it in hidden fields on page, and then access in server side code

Place two hidden fields on your aspx page. like

```
<asp:HiddenField id="hdffromdate" runat="server"></asp:textbox> 
<asp:HiddenField id="hdftodate" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
```

Set values in these hidden fields like

```
$('[id$=hdffromdate]').val(fromDate );
$('[id$=hdftodate]').val(toDate);
```

in your submit button click event handler

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      var fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(hdffromdate.Value);
      var toDate = Convert.ToDateTime(hdftodate.Value);
      //...
}
```

Comment: @Yograj-->oh thank you frd for your information,, could you send me the link for that jquey? and if it possible, give me example for that??